# how do I use $id to be number or new var in Firebase Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I have this `$scope` to call a table in Firebase named Questions

```
$scope.questions=$firebaseArray(fireBaseData.refQuestions());
```

and I call the database this way

```
{{questions}}
```

it shows exactly like this

```
[{"nama":"Perkataan yang saya sampaikan dapat diingat dan berkesan untuk orang lain.",
    "nilai":"item7",
    "$id":"1",
    "$priority":null
},
{"nama":"Saya sering mengucap “terimakasih” atas pertolongan orang lain agar terlihat ramah.",
    "nilai":"item6",
    "$id":"2", // THIS VALUE THAT I NEEDED
    "$priority":null
}]
```

**QUESTIONS:**

what I am looking for is to call just `$id value` like 2 to be new `var` or `$scope` so I cant make them to be question number

because I need new `var` or `$scope` such

```
$scope.questionNo = $firebaseArray(fireBaseData.refQuestions().$id);

$scope.question =;
$scope.totalQuestions = $scope.questions.length;
$scope.currentRoute = $scope.questionNo;
```

but failed

Answer (score 1):

Your question requires some clarification, but since StackOverflow won't let me post a comment, here it goes ...

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to access a particular question by it's $id, so you need to do the following:

```
$scope.questions = $firebaseArray(fireBaseData.refQuestions().orderByChild('$id').equalTo('2'));
$scope.question = $scope.questions[0];
```

You can check [angularfire docs](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/tree/master/docs/guide) and [firebase docs on filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

However this situation will benefit mostly from a different structure of your database, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data). It will be a lot easier to access questions by their $id if it was the key under which they were stored, in which case you could simply do

```
$scope.question = $firebaseObject(fireBaseData.refQuestions().child('2'));
```

Comment: well now it's more interesting than before, i tried your method

`$scope.question = $firebaseObject(fireBaseData.refQuestions().child('2'));`

but it shows like this

`{"$id":"2","$priority":null,"nama":"Saya sering mengucap “terimakasih” atas pertolongan orang lain agar terlihat ramah.","nilai":"item6"}`

what i need is just that '2' value become new variable, how can I just take that $id as a new $scope ?

Comment: You can put anything under $scope, it is just an object, so

Comment: You can put anything under $scope, it is just an object. You can do `$scope.questionNo = '2';` or `$scope.questionNo = $scope.question.$id`, or you can reference `$scope.question.$id` directly in the template.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i thought, but it's not working, 

    `$scope.question=$firebaseObject(fireBaseData.refQuestions());
      $scope.questionNo = $scope.question.$id;`

i dunno what I missed

Comment: `fireBaseData.refQuestions()` refers to the collection of objects and that doesn't have an $id property. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. What do you need the $id property for? Are you trying to display it in HTML, or do you need to do operations with it in the JS code ? Do you need to do that with all questions, or only a specific one and which one if so ?

Comment: i need that $id value for make some index route, to generate new route, so i can show a question per page, that's why i need like questionNo, total question, questionId, current route, question lenght, so when I get question $id is 2 as new variable, it refers me to question number 2, just like ParseInt while using general JSON

Comment: In this case you probably have to run a for() cycle over the collection of questions and access the $id in it. In JS that would look like `for (var q of $scope.questions) { var questionNo = q.$id; }`. You can do it in your template with ng-repeat like this - `<ul><li ng-repeat="q of questions">{{q.$id}}</li></ul>`